# Magento 2: Payment Method Not Capturing Shipping Address From Payment Page

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

On the `Checkout Page` after filling in the shipping address and checking the check box: my billing and shipping address are the same on the payment method

it returns the error:

> Please check the billing address information. `firstname` is required.
> Enter and try again. `lastname` is required. Enter and try again.
> "street" is required. Enter and try again. "city" is required. Enter
> and try again. "telephone" is required. Enter and try again.
> "postcode" is required. Enter and try again. `regionId` is required.
> Enter and try again.

It now requires that I uncheck the checkbox: my billing and shipping address are the same and enter a billing address there too for the order to be placed successfully.

I would prefer to just check the checkbox: my billing and shipping address are the same to place the order successfully.

[image: Screenshot of the Error]

Comment: I will check it today. What is your magento version?

Comment: Magento 2.3.0
Thank you

Comment: I am facing the same issue? Have you Solved your issue? Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: I am also facing same issue with onestepcheckout.`Please check the shipping address information. "firstname" is required. Enter and try again. "lastname" is required. Enter and try again. "street" is required. Enter and try again. "city" is required. Enter and try again. "telephone" is required. Enter and try again. "regionId" is required. Enter and try again.
` Can anyone help me to solve this issue.